# trying rereplace and replace to modify some data

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am suffering from regex illness, i am taking medicines but nothing happening, now i am stuck again with this issue

```
<cfset Change = replacenocase(mytext,'switch(cSelected) {',' var x = 0;while(x < cSelected.length){switch(cSelected[x]) {','one')>
```

this did not changed anything

i tried Rereplace too

```
<cfset Change = rereplacenocase(mytext,'[switch(cSelected) {]+',' var x = 0;while(x < cSelected.length){switch(cSelected[x]) {','one')>
```

this created weird results

Comment: It'd be better if you provide what you want the pattern for?

Comment: well, it is not a pattern, the thing is am doing is just making a replace with one thing with another, but i think space being the culprit here, which is not letting me do the replace, so that is my question

Comment: TBH, you are so far off with your regex, I think you need to step back and get up to speed with how the patterns work using smaller examples. I do a fairly thorough job of documenting CFML's regex implementation here: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2015/01/regular-expressions-in-cfml-link-summary.html. That might be a good place to start

Comment: What is the expected result? How is this different than the result you are getting? 'Created weird results' does not help us be able to help you.

Comment: well that replaced wherever it finds that, start of the script, anywhere it could, i am not sure rereplace will work here, if works how, i tried with ` \s`, but that is still not working, the only culprit i see is the space here

Comment: No, it's not the only potential thing wrong. You need to understand how to use regex patterns before you try to use them.

Comment: i am reading your blog, but it will take time and i am trying to solve this too...

Comment: Can we solve this or not

Comment: What have *you* done to try to solve it? And as Scott said: you're not really asking your question very coherently, nor really providing a decent amount of information. But what troubleshooting have you done? Have you put your pattern through any regex testers? Simply looking at it on http://regexper.com/#%5Bswitch(cSelected)%20%7B%5D%2B should give you a bit hint where you're going wrong. And whilst you're reading blog articles, give this one a read too: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/12/need-help-know-how-to-ask-for-it.html

Comment: @Adam: Enough of Lecture, Thanks, please do not solve it, I am reading the Blog post and i will solve myself. Old Man

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses, square brackets, and curly brackets are special characters in any implementation of RegEx. Wrapping something in `[square brackets]` means any of the characters within so `[fifty]` would match any of f,i,t,y. The plus sign after it just means to match any of these characters as many times as possible. So yes `[switch(cSelected) {]+` would replace `switch(cSelected) {`, but it would also replace any occurrence of switch, or s, or w, or the words `this` or `twitch()` because each character in these is represented in your character class.

As a regex, you would instead want `(switch\(cSelected\) \{)` (the `+` isn't useful here, and we have to *escape* the parentheses that we want literally represented. It is also a good idea to escape curly braces because they have special meaning in parts of regex and I believe that when you're new to regex, there's no such thing as *over-escaping*.

```
(switch            # Opens Capture Group
                     # Literal switch
 \(cSelected       # Literal (
                     # Literal cSelected
 \)                # Literal )
                     #   single space
 \{                # Literal {
)                  # Closes Capture Group
```

You can also try something like `(switch\(cSelected\)\s*\{)`, using the token `\s*` to represent *any number of whitespace characters*.

```
(switch            # Opens CG1
                     # Literal switch
 \(cSelected       # Literal (
                     # Literal cSelected
 \)                # Literal )
 \s*               # Token: \s for white space
                     # * repeats zero or more times
 \{                # Literal {
)                  # Closes CG1
```

What's needed, and the reason people can't be of much assistance is an excerpt from what you're trying to modify and more lines of code.

Potential reasons that the non-regex `ReplaceNoCase()` isn't working is either that it can't make the match it needs, which could be a whitespace issue, or it could be that you have two variables setting `Change` to an action based on the `mytext` variable..